# I want to fetch Group Chat's Unread comment list (mysql, SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, model

I have designed a group chat(read function with, user and staff are many to many) of table structure.

There is I want to get a list of unread messages of the staff, but I can not. If you write what a query, or will retrieve a list of unread messages.

SQL

```
    select * from chat as c inner join chat_group as cg on c.chat_group_id = cg.id left join chat_read cr on c.id = cr.chat_id
```

Table structure

```
    user: id, name

    staff: id, name

    chat_group: id, name

    chat: id, chat_group_id, user_id, staff_id, comment

    chat_read: id, chat_id, user_id, staff_id
```

Data example

```
    user:
    1, hoge_user
    2, foo_user

    staff:
    1, hoge_staff
    2, foo_staff

    chat_group:
    1, test_group

    chat:
    1, 1, null, 1, "hello hoge_staff"
    2, 1, 1, null, "hello hoge_user"

    chat_read: (Comments posted on their own will not be registered as read)
    1, 1, null, 1
    2, 2, 1, null
    3, 1, null, 2 <- foo staff also read not do anything
    4, 2, null, 2
```

Comment: In the comment or message table, you need another column 'Status' with values 0 and 1. 1 means already read and 0 means unread.

Comment: You need to include the results that you want to clarify what you want to do.  For instance, you say you want "unread messages", but nothing in your data model is called a "message" and it is not clear how to determine if something is "unread".

Answer (score 2):

From my perspective, you can have a flag inside the chat table where you can manage the status for the chat message.

so you can query like this:

```
select * from chat c, chat_group cg where c.chat_group_id = cg.id and c.status = 'READ';
```

You can make the flag as int and create an enum for managing it from your code. This is something similar we solved at https://www.applozic.com

Answer (score 0):

You question is rather ambiguous.  But I would expect a query to look something like this:

```
select c.*
from chat c
where c.staff_id is not null and -- a "staff message"
      not exists (select 1
                  from chat_read cr
                  where cr.chat_id = c.chat_id
                 );  -- is "unread"
```